# jQuery Issues having bootstrap 3.0 in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

Hey guys i have a very short period of time to fix all of my jQuery. I have it working great locally and no issues but i don't get why it breaks in side SharePoint.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening. I am exhausted and tried several things on my end to fix it but im breaking it.

Thank you all in advance for any help you can give.

```
// Header.js
// jQuery.noConflict();
;(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
    // Avoid following the href location when clicking
    e.preventDefault();
    // Avoid having the menu to close when clicking
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(function () {


// Closes Mobile Menu when resized
      $(window).bind("resize", function () {
          console.log($(this).width())
          if ($(this).width() > 750) {
              $('.navbar-collapse, .search-menu').removeClass('in');
              $('.navbar-toggle, .mobile-search').addClass('collapsed').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
          } else {
          }
      }).trigger('resize');
  })

// Mobile Menu Controls
  $('.mobile-search').click(function (e) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function (e) {
    $('.search-menu').collapse('hide');
  });


// Closes Menu Inside Menu
  $('.mega-nav-close').on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
  });

  $('.search-close').on('click', function() {
    $(".search-menu").removeClass("open");
  });

// Mobile Menu Back Button
  $('.submenu-back-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown-submenu").removeClass("open");
  });

  // Remove drop down when you click else where on page
  $('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').is(e.target)
    && $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0
    && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0
  ) {
    $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' );
  }
  });


  //QUICK LINKS Controls
  $(".mobile-quicklinks").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    // $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100);
    // return false;
  });

  // Toggle open class and reset script
  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]', 'ul.navbar-right').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    // Avoid following the href location when clicking
    event.preventDefault();
    // Avoid having the menu to close when clicking
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Toggle menu.
    if ($(this).find().parent().hasClass('open')){
    console.log($(this).html());
    $(this).find().parent().removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' );
  }else{
    $(this).parent().addClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' ).siblings('.mega-nav-item').animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    // If children are open, close them.
    $(this).children().removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' );
    // If a sibling menu is already open we close it
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' ).children().removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' ).siblings('.mega-nav-item').removeAttr( 'style' );
    $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('open').removeAttr( 'style' );


    var menu = $(this).parent().find("ul");
    var menupos = menu.offset();

    if ((menupos + menu.width()) + 30 > $(window).width()) {
        var newpos = - menu.width();
    } else {
        var newpos = $(this).parent().width();
    }
    menu.css({ 'left': 'newpos' });
  }
  });

// Submenu Controls Fading In and Out
$('a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
    // Do nothing needs to reset
    $('.nav-accordion').addClass('collapsed');
  else
    $('.nav-accordion').addClass('collapsed').attr('aria-expanded', 'false').children().addClass('collapsed').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $('.list-item-sublinks').removeClass('collapse in').addClass('collapse');
    $('.dropdown-submenu').removeAttr( 'style' );
  });

});
})(jQuery);
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/thrilom/pen/ayxXZN)

Comment: so when you say working locally, you mean just as an html file, not hosted in SharePoint at all? What have you tried to fix it? What is actually not working? Without any info it's hard to help. My first guess is that it's because SharePoint has it's own js libraries and mQuery I think it's called. That may use the $ alias, so it might be changing those to jQuery or something like that.

Comment: Are you getting any error message in your browser console ? If yes then share that too..:)

Comment: The navigation when clicking into a subnav to slide it out it is just closing the nav. preventDefault and stopPropagation are not working.

I have tried to redo the handling of the sub navigation many times but even if i simplify it to a basic script it still has the same affect when added to dynamic SharePoint code.

I am getting an access code to see any errors now. Please bare with me.